# Remove Unlisted Application

Tags: fedora, package-management, aws

I am running Fedora 37 on my home computer, and have attempted to install Amazon Workspaces via Flatpak, which was successful (package: `‘app/com.amazon.Workspaces/x86_64/stable’`).  I was having issues with the application and had attempted to uninstall it - which according to Flatpak's CLI, was successful. Within the 'Software' store, it also shows the application as an install candidate and **not currently** installed. However, this application is listed in my app drawer, and can successfully launch.

I am making the assumption that this may have been installed by `dpkg` but cannot be certain. It does not show as an installed package when I attempt to `dnf remove` it does not show as an installed candidate, nor is it found when I run `rpm -qa | grep work` .

If I attempt to "open files" from Task Manager when launching the app, it crashes. If I check the running process, I can locate the running app:

```
↪ ps -aux | grep works
michael+   13267  1.8  0.4 4462024 144492 ?      Sl   10:25   0:01 /opt/workspacesclient/workspacesclient
```

I can simply delete the directory (once ending all process), but is this the *cleanest* method to do? What am I missing in terms of package managment?

Comment: Why do you have `dpkg` in Fedora?

Comment: @Roflo, because, uh....it was installed. by *something*.